# Entity Framework Core bug?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Can anyone confirm this if this is a bug in Entity Framework Core?

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [CreatedById] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedById] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NULL,
    [Id] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](150) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_Users_CreatedById] 
        FOREIGN KEY([CreatedById]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_Users_UpdatedById] 
        FOREIGN KEY([UpdatedById]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id])
GO
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Users] ([CreatedById], [UpdatedById], [Id], [Name]) 
VALUES (N'2cfc1025-cf96-4929-a6a4-e2ed77a6ae12', N'2cfc1025-cf96-4929-a6a4-e2ed77a6ae12', N'2cfc1025-cf96-4929-a6a4-e2ed77a6ae12', N'Admin'),
       (N'2cfc1025-cf96-4929-a6a4-e2ed77a6ae12', N'60ca72c4-db2d-4cea-9981-c10d6942a11e', N'60ca72c4-db2d-4cea-9981-c10d6942a11e', N'User 01'),
       (N'60ca72c4-db2d-4cea-9981-c10d6942a11e', NULL, N'40719114-f53e-4d3f-9a1b-49f63b18002b', N'New User')
```

Model

```
  [Table("Users")]
    public partial class User 
    {
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Guid CreatedById { get; set; }
        public Guid? UpdatedById { get; set; }

    }
```

Entity Framework 6.2 (`.EDMX`) code:

```
using (var context = new Agap2TestEntities())
{
   var test = context.Users.Include(p => p.User1).Include(p =>p.User2).ToList();
   Console.WriteLine(test.Count);
}
```

SQL generated

```
   SELECT
        1 AS [C1],
        [Extent1].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById],
        [Extent1].[UpdatedById] AS [UpdatedById],
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
        [Extent2].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById1],
        [Extent2].[UpdatedById] AS [UpdatedById1],
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1],
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1],
        [Extent3].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById2],
        [Extent3].[UpdatedById] AS [UpdatedById2],
        [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2],
        [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name2]
        FROM   [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CreatedById] = [Extent2].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[UpdatedById] = [Extent3].[Id]
```

Returns 3 records, it's Ok!

Entity Framework Core 2.1.4

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) {}
}

class Program
{
    private static ApplicationDbContext CreateContext()
    {
         return new ApplicationDbContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>().UseSqlServer("Server=...").Options);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var dbContext = CreateContext())
        {
            var test = dbContext.Set<User>().Include(p => p.CreatedBy).Include(p => p.UpdatedBy).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(test.Count);
        }
   }
}
```

Sql Generated

```
SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[CreatedById], [p].[Name], [p].[UpdatedById], [p.UpdatedBy].[Id], [p.UpdatedBy].[CreatedById], [p.UpdatedBy].[Name], [p.UpdatedBy].[UpdatedById], [p.CreatedBy].[Id], [p.CreatedBy].[CreatedById], [p.CreatedBy].[Name], [p.CreatedBy].[UpdatedById]
FROM [Users] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [Users] AS [p.UpdatedBy] ON [p].[Id] = [p.UpdatedBy].[CreatedById]
INNER JOIN [Users] AS [p.CreatedBy] ON [p].[CreatedById] = [p.CreatedBy].[Id]
```

Returns 4 records, KO!

This line "LEFT JOIN [Users] AS [p.UpdatedBy] ON [p].[Id] = [p.UpdatedBy].[CreatedById]" is wrong!

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your question, how are you proving that there are 3 records and that there are 4 records? And when there are 4 records, what's in the Db? And what's the extra record contain? The absence of these answers makes your question extremely difficult to even attempt to answer

Comment: I have a hard time believing that EF Core contains a bug that creates a record out of thin air. Please post your test setup.

Comment: @nvoigt use the sql script to create the table, use the insert scripts to populate the table, create a console application, use "Entity Framework Core 2.1.4" code that i posted.

Comment: @MarkC. watching test variable, there are 2 "user Admin" records instead of just one

Comment: Add `Database.Log = message => Console.WriteLine(message);` as body of your `ApplicationDbContext` constructor to find out what's going on.

Comment: @nvoigt Database.Logo does not exists in Core, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2017/09/22/simple-logging-for-ef-core/ But i will try that

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro that.  A ran that SQL and scaffolded a model from the database.  The query

```
 db.Set<Users>().Include(p => p.CreatedBy).Include(p => p.UpdatedBy).ToList();
```

translated correctly as

```
SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[CreatedById], [p].[Name], [p].[UpdatedById], [p.UpdatedBy].[Id], [p.UpdatedBy].[CreatedById], [p.UpdatedBy].[Name], [p.UpdatedBy].[UpdatedById], [p.CreatedBy].[Id], [p.CreatedBy].[CreatedById], [p.CreatedBy].[Name], [p.CreatedBy].[UpdatedById]
FROM [Users] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [Users] AS [p.UpdatedBy] ON [p].[UpdatedById] = [p.UpdatedBy].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Users] AS [p.CreatedBy] ON [p].[CreatedById] = [p.CreatedBy].[Id]
```

Here is the generated DbContext:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace EfCoreTest
{
    public partial class FooContext : DbContext
    {
        public FooContext()
        {
        }

        public FooContext(DbContextOptions<FooContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=.;database=Foo;Integrated Security=true");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Users>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(150);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.CreatedBy)
                    .WithMany(p => p.InverseCreatedBy)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CreatedById)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.UpdatedBy)
                    .WithMany(p => p.InverseUpdatedBy)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UpdatedById);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and the generated Entity class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EfCoreTest
{
    public partial class Users
    {
        public Users()
        {
            InverseCreatedBy = new HashSet<Users>();
            InverseUpdatedBy = new HashSet<Users>();
        }

        public Guid CreatedById { get; set; }
        public Guid? UpdatedById { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Users CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Users UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Users> InverseCreatedBy { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Users> InverseUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use my model code? full example here https://github.com/parxal/EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: No I created your SQL Server tables and ran scaffold-DbContext.  I looked at your code, and your entity is configured only by convention.  So something is going wrong when EF generates a model from your C# making it not match your database.  I'll update the answer with the generated entity and DbContext.

Comment: Please Check : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13573

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for following up with a repro and an issue on the EF Core conventions for the team.